# PHP : Returning two separate queries different results within a function in php

Tags: php

i used two functions to get two different query results.

Can i get these two different query results using one function??

Thanks for any help
 you can provide.

```
 public function referralDoctorData($ReferredByIdUser)
{
    try
    {
        $referralDoctorDataQuery = $this->PDOconn->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM tuserlist AS a
            LEFT JOIN tdoctorprofilelist AS b
                ON a.IdUser = b.RefIdUser
            WHERE
                a.IdUser = $ReferredByIdUser
            ");
        $referralDoctorDataQuery->execute();
        $referralDoctorData = $referralDoctorDataQuery->fetch();
        return $referralDoctorData;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function invoiceItemList($InvoiceId)
{
    try
    {
        $invoiceItemListQuery = $this->PDOconn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tlabinvoiceitemdetails WHERE RefInvoiceId='".$InvoiceId."' ");
        $invoiceItemListQuery->execute();
        $invoiceItemList = $invoiceItemListQuery->fetchAll();
        return $invoiceItemList;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: both of these functions are susceptible to an SQL injection as you are not using PDO correctly

Comment: Probably! But unless we know what columns would link the tables we can only make **guesses**

Comment: Why would you want these as 1 functions? They don't seem related (invoices and referral doctors?). If you can explain the functionality a bit and how these table link as to why you'd need 1 function, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can get those results with one function, just return them as an array.

> BUT as viion pointed out in the comments, why do you even want that?
>   They dont seem to be related and it makes the code much more readable
>   if those 2 functions stay seperated.

If you want to merge the functions anyway, here is an attempt on how you would do it.

```
public function getReferralDoctorDataAndInvoiceItemList($ReferredByIdUser)
{
    $returnArray = array();
    try
    {
        $referralDoctorDataQuery = $this->PDOconn->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM tuserlist AS a
            LEFT JOIN tdoctorprofilelist AS b
                ON a.IdUser = b.RefIdUser
            WHERE
                a.IdUser = $ReferredByIdUser
            ");
        $referralDoctorDataQuery->execute();
        $referralDoctorData = $referralDoctorDataQuery->fetch();
        $returnArray['referralDoctorData'] = $referralDoctorData;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    try
    {
        $invoiceItemListQuery = $this->PDOconn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tlabinvoiceitemdetails WHERE RefInvoiceId='".$InvoiceId."' ");
        $invoiceItemListQuery->execute();
        $invoiceItemList = $invoiceItemListQuery->fetchAll();
        $returnArray['invoiceItemList'] = $invoiceItemList;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

> In my code I did not correct your usage of PDO (since I havent ever
>   used PDO myself) but as I understand PDO it should be used like
>   Jokatek mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to do two different things with one function. If you have two queries with different results you should also use different functions, but if you want only one function, you should try to encapsulate your functions with a facade class.

But you should also use PDO in the right way, for example your first statement.

```
$referralDoctorDataQuery = $this->PDOconn->prepare(
'SELECT * FROM tuserlist AS a
            LEFT JOIN tdoctorprofilelist AS b
                ON a.IdUser = b.RefIdUser
            WHERE
                a.IdUser = :userId'
);
        $referralDoctorDataQuery->execute(array('userId' => $ReferredByIdUser));
```